# Test a web service client using JAX-WS

Tags: api, jax-ws

There is an api called "HelloWorld" on the link shown in code below. How can I call this api using the code below. The api takes no parameters.

The service already exists on the url shown. What do I need to add to the code below:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

public class apiHelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://project.url.com/service.asmx?wsdl");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL suggest that you are pointing to [wsdl](/questions/tagged/wsdl) document, not the actual service. Most likely your service is under the same URL but without `?wsdl` suffic).

That being said calling SOAP web service using plain `URL` class requires few extra steps. But it's absolutely possible, after all this is a plain HTTP protocol.

You need a SOAP request in XML format, including SOAP Envelope. This might be the most complex part (example taken from: [*Sending a SOAP request to a Web Service via URLConnection*](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2006/05/25/sending-a-soap-request-to-a-web-se/)):

```
String soapXml =   //...;
java.net.URLConnection conn = new URL("http://project.url.com/service.asmx").openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(soapXml);
wr.flush();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

By reading `rd` you can fetch the response.

Comment: where do I insert the call to HelloWorld()

Comment: @IbexyI: the operation name goes into `soapXml` string. See [sample SOAP request](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_example.asp).

Comment: Here is my code: [code]   String soapXml = "HelloWorld";  //...;
  java.net.URLConnection conn = new URL("http://project.url.com/service.asmx").openConnection();
  conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "");
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
  wr.write(soapXml);
  wr.flush();

  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  System.out.println(rd.toString());[code]

Comment: The above still does not work. Sorry I could not format it properly

Comment: @IbexyI: you cannot just send `"HelloWorld"` string. SOAP request must be well-formatted XML request, see link above for samples.

Comment: There has got to be an easy way to set reference to a wsdl link and call a method from it called "HelloWorld".